# Having Trouble finding a simplified power series representation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series, partial-fractions

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Partial fractions seemed the most efficient route to take. However, I am having trouble at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your trouble at the end? $(-x)^n=(-1)^nx^n$, so you got $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2\cdot (-1)^n -1\right)x^n$$
Note the coefficients only depend on whether $n$ is even or odd.

In any event, it is possibly easier to do this as $$(1-3x)\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}=(1-3x)\left(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots\right)$$

Comment: Thanks Thomas, and as stupid as it sounds.... how did you combine the 2 sums to achieve ∑(2•((-1)^n)-1)x^n.

Comment: $\sum_n 2(-x)^n - \sum_n x^n = \sum_n (2(-1)^n x^n -x^n)=\sum_n (2\cdot  (-1)^n -1)x^n$.

Comment: My man. I appreciate the help